# Binding rows from synonymous columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm importing a lot of different data frames. Due to the fieldworkers using different notations, there are many different synonyms to a column. This creates an issue when I row bind the data.frames together, as there now exists many superfluous columns to describe the same thing. Sometimes they are just misspelt. The order and number of columns in each import varies.

For example: PARCELL may be spelt PAR, PARC, PARCEL, and so on.
             ROWNR may be spelt ROW, ROWNUMBER, etc.

Example data:

Field 1

```
X1    BLOCK PARCELL ROW SORTNR FUKTIGH PLANTNR KONDI SKADA1 SKADA2 SKADA3 OVRIGT X13  
  <lgl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  <lgl>
1 NA        1       1     1     13       3       1     1     NA     NA     NA NA     NA   
2 NA        1       1     1     13       3       2     1     NA     NA     NA NA     NA   
3 NA        1       1     1     13       3       3     1     NA     NA     NA NA     NA   
4 NA        1       1     1     13       3       4     3    513     NA     NA NA     NA   
5 NA        1       1     1     13       3       5     1     NA     NA     NA NA     NA   
6 NA        1       1     1     13       3       6     1     NA     NA     NA NA     NA
```

Field 2

```
  X1    BL PARC ROWNR SORTNR PLANTNR DOD85  KOND  HOJD SKAD1 SKAD2 X12  
  <lgl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
1 NA        1       1     1     17       1     0     1    87    NA    NA NA   
2 NA        1       1     1     17       2     0     1    83    NA    NA NA   
3 NA        1       1     1     17       3     0     1    67    NA    NA NA   
4 NA        1       1     1     17       4     0     1    77    NA    NA NA   
5 NA        1       1     1     17       5     0     1    50   151    NA NA   
6 NA        1       1     1     17       6     0     1    59   151    NA NA
```

Of course, you can run around this by manually parsing each the proper name when importing the data, or using dplyr::rename but as there are many different imports this becomes unpractical.

I already have all of my data.frames in a named list, data.frame.list, so it might be good to iterate over this: lapply, for?

```r
library(dplyr)

data.frame.list <- mget(ls(pattern="^F"))
finaldf <- data.frame.list %>% bind_rows(.id="id")
```

I would like to be able to provide R with some identified synonyms before row binding so as to be able to avoid manually correcting these for each data.frame individually.

My expected output would look like the following:

PARCEL; ROWNR;

1;1

1;2

1;3

1;4

2;1

2;2

2;3

I'm not interested in keeping track of how the original field worker spelt parcel or row. I am only concerned with having the values under the correct column.

TLDR; Want to combine data with many mispelt columns, preferably by iterating a rowbind over a list and parsing synonyms to be joined under one column - e.g.

PARCEL = c("PAR", "PA", "PARCELL", "PARCEL")

ROW = c("ROW", "Row", "ROWNR", "ROWNUMBER")

Answer (score 0):

`data.table::rbindlist()` might be what you are looking for.. Though I am not sure because of the lack of sample data and a desired output example.

**updated answer based on sample data provided**

```
dt1 <- fread("
X1    BLOCK PARCELL ROW SORTNR FUKTIGH PLANTNR KONDI SKADA1 SKADA2 SKADA3 OVRIGT X13  
NA        1       1     1     13       3       1     1     NA     NA     NA NA     NA   
NA        1       1     1     13       3       2     1     NA     NA     NA NA     NA   
NA        1       1     1     13       3       3     1     NA     NA     NA NA     NA   
NA        1       1     1     13       3       4     3    513     NA     NA NA     NA   
NA        1       1     1     13       3       5     1     NA     NA     NA NA     NA   
NA        1       1     1     13       3       6     1     NA     NA     NA NA     NA")

dt2 <- fread("
X1    BL PARC ROWNR SORTNR PLANTNR DOD85  KOND  HOJD SKAD1 SKAD2 X12  
NA        1       1     1     17       1     0     1    87    NA    NA NA   
NA        1       1     1     17       2     0     1    83    NA    NA NA   
NA        1       1     1     17       3     0     1    67    NA    NA NA   
NA        1       1     1     17       4     0     1    77    NA    NA NA   
NA        1       1     1     17       5     0     1    50   151    NA NA   
NA        1       1     1     17       6     0     1    59   151    NA NA")

l <- mget( ls (pattern = "^dt"))

#only keep columns with names that possibly contain parcels
PARCEL = c("PAR", "PA", "PARCELL", "PARCEL")
ROW    = c("ROW", "Row", "ROWNR", "ROWNUMBER")

l2 <- lapply( l, function(x) {
  rows    <- x[, grepl( paste0( ROW, collapse = "|" ), names(x) ), with = FALSE]
  parcels <- x[, grepl( paste0( PARCEL, collapse = "|" ), names(x) ), with = FALSE]
  ans <- data.table( row = rows, parcel = parcels )
  setnames( ans, names(ans), c("row", "parcel"))
  return(ans)
})

rbindlist( l2, use.names = FALSE, idcol = TRUE)

#    .id row parcel
# 1: dt1   1      1
# 2: dt1   1      1
# 3: dt1   1      1
# 4: dt1   1      1
# 5: dt1   1      1
# 6: dt1   1      1
# 7: dt2   1      1
# 8: dt2   1      1
# 9: dt2   1      1
# 10:dt2   1      1
# 11:dt2   1      1
# 12:dt2   1      1
```

**old answer**

This code works, as long as the columns in the data.frames/data.tables in `l` are always in the same order.

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table( parcel = 1:2 )
dt2 <- data.table( parcell = 1:2 )

l <- mget( ls( pattern = "^dt" ) )

rbindlist( l, use.names = FALSE, idcol = "object" )

#    object parcel
# 1:    dt1      1
# 2:    dt1      2
# 3:    dt2      1
# 4:    dt2      2
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is close but not quite what I'm looking for. I have updated my question to better reflect the issues which arose when reading your answer. The amount of columns can vary between imports and do not always come in the same order.

Comment: Please add some relevant sample data to your question, so I can update my answer accodingly.